# Multiple summary statistics on grouped column in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying below code to work with Julia(1.5.3), Its just a representation of what I am trying to do.

```
using DataFrames
using DataFramesMeta
using RDatasets

## setup
iris = dataset("datasets", "iris")
gdf = groupby(iris, :Species)

## Applying the split combine
## This code works fine
combine(gdf, nrow, (valuecols(gdf) .=> mean))
```

But, when I try to do it for multiple summary it fails

```
 combine(gdf, nrow, (valuecols(gdf) .=> [mean, sum]))
```

**Error**:

> ERROR: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common
> size; got a dimension with lengths 4 and 2")

Little debug on error suggests that If I change my code to this:

```
combine(gdf, nrow, ([:SepalLength, :PetalLength] .=> [mean,sum]))
## This code works but its still not correct as it doesn't tell me the mean and sum of both the columns , rather mean for SepalLength and sum for PetalLength, which was expected as per previous error
```

A little more research into it and I realized that, we can do something like this, this result is correct but the outcome is in long form of table not the wide form. I was expecting this would have given me the answer to my question, but it seems it doesn't work as expected.

```
 combine(gdf, ([:SepalWidth, :PetalWidth] .=>  x -> ([sum(x), mean(x)])))

 ## The code above works but output is 6x3 DataFrame, I was expecting 3x6 DataFrame
```

**My question is**:

Is there any way to use split combine in such a way that I get a wide table like below (I have used "do end" with "combine" to generate it). I am okay with this solution, but I need to type out all the column here, Is there any way such that I can get all the summary stats(sum, median, mean etc) as columns for all the column provided in combine. I hope my question is clear, Please point out in case its a duplicate or its not well communicated. Thanks

```
combine(gdf) do x
    return(sw_sum = sum(x.SepalWidth), 
           sw_mean = mean(x.SepalWidth), 
           sp_mean = mean(x.PetalWidth), 
           sp_sum = sum(x.PetalWidth)
          )
end



## My expected answer should be similar to this
#3×5 DataFrame
# Row │ Species     sw_sum   sw_mean  sp_mean  sp_sum
#     │ Cat…        Float64  Float64  Float64  Float64
#─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────
#   1 │ setosa        171.4    3.428    0.246     12.3
#   2 │ versicolor    138.5    2.77     1.326     66.3
#   3 │ virginica     148.7    2.974    2.026    101.3
```

Also, this works:

```
 combine(gdf, [:1] .=> [mean, sum, minimum, maximum,median])
```

But this doesn't and throws the dimension error like above, still scratching my head over this:

```
combine(gdf, [:1, :2] .=> [mean, sum, minimum, maximum,median])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do:

```
 combine(gdf, nrow, vec(valuecols(gdf) .=> [mean sum]))
```

or

```
 combine(gdf, nrow, (valuecols(gdf) .=> [mean sum])...)
```

or

```
 combine(gdf, nrow, [n => f for n in valuecols(gdf) for f in [mean sum]])
```

(note that there is no comma between `mean` and `sum`)

The reason is that you need to add an additional dimension to broadcasted `.=>` in order to get all combinations of inputs.

EDIT:

`...` just iterates a collection and passes its elements as consecutive positional arguments to the function, e.g.:

```
julia> f(x...) = x
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(1, [2,3,4]...)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: I was writing it from my head and have forgotten to flatten the result. Fixed

Comment: Thank you , all of the solutions worked like charm. One request if its possible,can you please add little detail on how to second solution is working. I got first and third, but could not able to understand ellipsis, Is it similar to python *args?, meanwhile i  am doing my research on ellipsis, Again Thank you

Comment: I have added an explanation. Is it clearer now?