# Apply multiple functions to a single column in Julia DataFrames.jl

Tags: dataframe, julia

I would like to easily apply multiple functions to a single column in a Julia dataframe. Here is a simple example from notebook 5 of the DataFrames.jl course on Julia Academy.

Bogumil shows us to easily calculate the mean of the `jumps` column by doing the following:

```
combine(df, :jumps => mean)
```

|  | jumps_mean |
| --- | --- |
|  | Float64 |
| 1 | 2.7186 |

But what if I want to apply multiple functions to `jumps` to get multiple summary statistics? So far I can get the following to work:

```
combine(df, :jumps => (x -> [(mean(x), std(x), minimum(x), maximum(x))]) => [:mean, :std, :min, :max])
```

|  | mean | std | max | min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Float64 | Float64 | Int64 | Int64 |
| 1 | 2.7186 | 0.875671 | 2 | 11 |

Is there a cleaner syntax for doing this, without needing wrap the function return in `[ ]` or specifically use an anonymous function?

For example, I would like to do:

```
combine(df, :jumps => (mean, std, minimum, maximum))
```

Answer (score 5):

Do:

```
combine(df, :jumps .=> [mean, std, minimum, maximum])
```

See also [Multiple summary statistics on grouped column in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66350756/multiple-summary-statistics-on-grouped-column-in-julia) for some more advanced examples.